# むにゅっとしてました。Meaning?

Tags: translation

[image]

Im having a hard time figuring out what this is trying to say, as there is no context (I haven't seen the anime) and it's all in hiragana. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is all hiragana just because nothing can be written in Kanji.

- ぎょえ(+ extra え） is an onomatopoeia representing the sound of a cry - meaning amazement/shock. (A different but similar: Godzilla's roar can be ぎゃおー)
- むにゅ is an onomatopoeia meaning softness of plastic material (e.g. clay). Here it may be breast.

The sentences per se means just what they say: *Wow. It was soft. It was*.